# Closure for Legendre Polynomials

Tags: partial-differential-equations, convergence-divergence, spherical-coordinates, legendre-polynomials, spherical-harmonics

Suppose I have a PDE which can be solved by an expansion on the Legendre Polynomial basis, for an axisymmetric problem in spherical coordinates.

For the derivation for such a problem, see [these notes](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/reh10/lectures/nst-mmii-chapter2.pdf), pp. 6/24-7/25)

Given:

> $\nabla^2 \Phi(r,\theta) = 0$

The solution is:

> $\Phi(r,\theta)=\sum_\limits{n=0}^{\infty}\left(A_n r^n + B_n r^{-(n+1)}\right) P_n (\cos\theta)$

This equation can be and *is* (frequently) used to solve the homogeneous Laplace and non-homogeneous Poisson equation in this coordinate system and the domain $r \in [r_{min},r_{max}]$ (where $0 \le r_{min} \lt r_{max} \le \infty$) and $\theta \in [0,\pi]$. Uniqueness of the solution and closure relations aren't too difficult for those familiar with this approach to solving PDEs.

My question is this:

What if the domain doesn't reach to the poles? What if instead of $\theta \in [0,\pi]$, the domain for $\theta$ is $\theta \in [\epsilon,\pi-\epsilon]$? Would I still be able to use the same techniques to solve for $\Phi(r,\theta)$ on this *reduced* domain as I would for the *full* domain? Would there be any consequences to using a reduced domain, such as new closure or uniqueness?

Comment: If you have a function $f$ on $[0,\pi]$ that is $0$ on $[0,\epsilon]\cup[\pi-\epsilon,\epsilon]$, then the $L^{2}$ expansion in Legendre polynomials would still converge in $(\epsilon,\pi-\epsilon)$, assuming standard Fourier conditions  for $f$ on $[\epsilon,\pi-\epsilon]$. That's probably all you need to consider for the problem at hand.

Comment: @TrialAndError: What "standard Fourier conditions"? When I think of Fourier-anything, I think of periodic functions. The variable $\theta$ is not periodic.

Comment: left- and right- derivatives at every point. Of bounded variation on the interval. Holder continuous. Those are all standard sorts of conditions leading to pointwise converge to the mean of the left- and right- hand limits for the ordinary Fourier series. And most of the same conditions apply to Legendre expansions, too.